# Массивы в php

Tags: php, база-данных, соцсети, mysql

В общем я вытаскиваю с БД подписки

```
        $subscriptions = fetch(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE id_user = '$my_id'"));
```

Потом мне надо получить сообщения всех этих подписок и отсортировать их по дате

```
     $posts = array();
    foreach($subscriptions as $subscription) {
       $id_subscribe = $subscription['id_subscriptions'];
       $posts = array_merge(fetch(mysql_query("SELECT *
                            FROM posts
                            JOIN users ON users.id =  '$id'
                            WHERE author = '$id_subscribe'
                            ORDER BY time DESC 
                            LIMIT 15")));
    }
```

И тут проблема в том, что мне надо получить массив вида

```
 $posts[i]['text'],
```

а не

```
 $posts[i][i]['text']
```

Comment: ну тогда может завести в цикле еще одну переменную, которая и будет иметь вид  $postsvar[i]. А так у вас в итоге само собой должен получиться массив массивов (fetch возвращает массив, который добавляется к массиву $posts)

Comment: @fleg сорри я не понял, что вы хотите. У меня потом в html стоит еще один foreach, который и создает посты, а если будет $posts[i][i]['text'], то он не будет работать и темболее посты будут в ленте расположены не по времени

Comment: mb [array_merge()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php) ? типа $posts=array_merge(fetch(mysql_query("...")), но это не быстро

btw [**mysql** устарел](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php), не используйте.

Comment: просто я хотел сказать что в таком виде как сейчас у Ыас получается 3-х мерный массив $posts из-за того, что в цикле Вы в него каждую итерацию записываете массив (2-х мерный), который возвращает fetch(...).
Я так понял, что вам из этого 3-х мерного массива нужно получить один единственный 2-х мерный, который будет относится к конкретному id_subscriptions. 
Соответственно для этого массива и предложил ввести новую переменную

Comment: ну да, мне надо получить один двух мерный массив с собранными постами моих подписок, который отсортирован по времени. Например я подписан на двоих(id 13 и 14), значит мне надо собрать все посты от авторов 13 и 14 и отсортировать их по времени, что-бы они были в перемешку

Comment: тогда @eicto прав, надо array_merge использовать, только потом результат еще раз прогнать через цикл, который все по времени отсортирует

Comment: @eicto сделал, как вы говорили, но теперь $posts содержит только посты с последней итерации цикла, с последней подписки. Посмотрите вопрос я изменил

Comment: @Zow, эмм, конечно, вы ведь записываете новые данные в `$posts` в каждой итерации. Вам нужно писать не `$posts = `, а `$posts[] = `.

Comment: не совсем так
скорее наверно надо писать 
$posts = array_merge($posts,fetch(...
array_merge принимает несколько массивов как аргументы
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php

Comment: @fleg, а, ну да, но и `[]` обязательно, иначе смысл в цикле?

Comment: у меня есть еще идея использовать array_push совместно с call_user_func_array но что-то мне лень реализацию делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, реализовал, то о чем говорил в последнем коменте:

```
function array_push_array(&$arr1,&$arr2) {
        array_unshift($arr2,"");
        $arr2[0]=&$arr1;
        call_user_func_array("array_push",$arr2);
        array_shift($arr1);
}
```

скорость не проверял, но мне кажется должно быть быстрее и честнее, чем merge.

[демо](http://ideone.com/HxrYHx)

Comment: @eicto спасибо, но появился пустой, когда начинает приписываться еще один

Comment: не очень понял откуда пустой массив может взяться.
ваша программа должна выглядеть примерно так:

    $posts=[];
    foreach($subscriptions as $subscription) {
       $id_subscribe = $subscription['id_subscriptions'];
       $data=fetch(mysql_query("SELECT *
                            FROM posts
                            JOIN users ON users.id =  '$id'
                            WHERE author = '$id_subscribe'
                            ORDER BY time DESC 
                            LIMIT 15")));
       array_push_array($posts,$data)
    }

Comment: если fetch всегда array, то все должно работать как надо.

Comment: все я понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

[[@Construct](/users/4463/construct)](/users/4463/construct), `array_merge($posts,fetch(...` заменит [], вернее даже не заменит а станет лучшей альтернативой, т.к. [] добавляют в массив один элемент, а `array_merge` добавит сразу несколько.

Но в итоге, даже при правильном использовании `array_merge`, массив `$posts` не будет отсортирован по дате, и его все равно надо прогнать как минимум еще через один цикл

Comment: Ааа, вы имели в виду одним из аргументов мерджа сделать сам `posts`, а, тогда понятно, конечно, `[]` не нужно.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста написать кодом, как,это будет выглядеть, так намного легче понять

Answer (score 0):

А что если сделать так?

```
$posts = array();
foreach($subscriptions as $subscription) {
   $id_subscribe = $subscription['id_subscriptions'];
   $posts[] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT *
                        FROM posts
                        JOIN users ON users.id =  '$id'
                        WHERE author = '$id_subscribe'
                        ORDER BY time DESC 
                        LIMIT 0,1"));
}
```